# Tempus in "Herausforderungen, die seit dem Krieg zu meistern ..."

Tags: grammar, tense

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Aber nun steht das Land vor einer der größten Herausforderungen, die seit dem Krieg zu meistern **waren**.

Normalerweise verwendet man im Deutschen das Präsens, wenn man sich auf ein Ereignis bezieht, das in der Vergangenheit beginnt, aber auch bis jetzt läuft:

> Ich **wohne** seit zwei Jahren in Köln.

Im Spiegel-Auszug verweist man auf Herausforderungen zwischen dem Zeitpunkt des Krieges und jetzt. Das schließt auch heutige Herausforderungen ein. Warum denn "waren"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zwischen dem Krieg und der Gegenwart stand das Land vor diversen Herausforderungen, die aber in der Vergangenheit bereits *bewältigt worden sind*, daher das Präteritum. Das Präsens ergäbe nur dann Sinn, wenn zu bestehenden Herausforderungen eine weitere hinzukäme:

> Aber nun steht das Land vor einer der größten (der) Herausforderungen, die seit dem Krieg zu meistern **sind**.

Die Formulierung ist an sich unglücklich, mit dem eingefügten "der" wird sie schöner. Hier dauert die Bewältigung noch an und das Präsens ist richtig.

Comment: Die Argumentation passt. Das zusätzliche "der" macht den Satz aber nur komplizierter, ohne Substanz hinzuzufügen. Kürzer und prägnanter wäre "Aber nun steht das Land vor einer der größten Herausforderungen seit dem Krieg." Kein Präteritum, kein Problem.

Comment: Jupp, `Herausforderungen` sind zum meistern da. Das ist der Normalzustand. Ein zusätzlicher Nebensatz ist nur dann notwendig, wenn die dort gelieferten Informationen vom Normalzustand abweichen.

Comment: @guidot Es ging ja nicht darum, den Satz zu verbessern, sondern zu erklären, warum da Präteritum steht. Deswegen wollte ich möglichst nah am Ursprungssatze bleiben und habe mir auch das Dativ-e verkniffen...